# Intersection of graph of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At how many points will the graph of the following functions intersect each other?$$
f(x)= e^{x^{12}},\quad g(x)=x^{12}. \quad x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Thank you in advance for your efforts.

Comment: Please show some efforts for solving the problem, otherwise close votes are likely to occur…

Comment: Hint: $\mathrm e^u>u$ for $u\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: There are no real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I personally thought alot in this matter. What came to my mind that they will intersect each other at 3 points. The one is exponential function the other is prabola. The intersection of two points is clear but the third one is as both will go to infinity and exponential function will attain infinity first and the parabola will attain second so at some point $<\infty$ they will intersect.